# How to read lines from a text file and store as char array?

Tags: c, arrays, char, text-files

I have an input text file with some instructions and, starting with line 7, several lines of text. Something like this:

```
hi gBroThuo oWdbmna eo mt ce oneain,nDustuh o n
Ade ds,bpopoonf  oneigno abro wmt  eIw
n,Yrtyt hlil t .s Ble a  meyboefr rtIhoyod
wla rimw yidehl. kes ,oyn L  af
fu;AcMadmdnae  nddmh ita behsctr rft iHdo"l,sie g"hu!,n eoaecMBt-
- h
```

I need to store the text to be stored in a `char` array (including the new line characters). What functions can I used to read and store this text to a single `char` array?

Answer (score 1):

```
char fileBuf[MAXFILE];
FILE *f;
int c;
size_t i;

if (f = fopen("filename", "r")) {
    for (i = 0; i < (MAXFILE - 1) && (c = getc(f)) != EOF; ++i)
        fileBuf[i] = c;
    fclose(f);
} else perror("Could not open file");
```

EDIT: you said you wanted to skip the first 7 lines.

```
int x;
char line[MAXLINE];
for (x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
    fgets(line, MAXLINE, f); /* skips first 7 lines, so now file pointer
                                will point to data after the 7 lines */
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while(fscanf(inputFile, %c, &charArray[i])!=EOF)
   i++;
```